Auto-upgrade version in service A when new version of library B is released Gradle
Our team have a service A(Kotlin & Gradle) which uses a domain library B(Kotlin & Gradle). The domain library B is versioned so when new changes occurs, the version is increased, then we update the version in service A. Last week, we had an incident in production because someone forgot to update the version of the library B in service A. Give me some good suggestions on how should we approach this.
We use GitHub & GitHub Actions, Slack and DataDog.
I have some ideas, but I'm not sure if there are any else options.

On releasing a new version of library B, notify the team's Slack channel that a new version was released and a new PR needs to be raised to update the version in service B (but this option won't ensure that people will really create a new PR and update the version in service A)
Trigger a DataDog alert to notice the team that a new version of library B is available (similar with option 1, but maybe it will look more like an emergency as a DataDog alert)
I was thinking about some GitHub action that on releasing library B will automatically send a Slack notification & create a PR for upgrading the library in Gradle's service A, but I'm not sure if it's possible.
I read something about Dependabot, but I'm not sure it is possible to use it for libraries that are not on public Maven repository and don't know really how it works.
Maybe any other option/examples from you :D

Thanks a lot for any answers!

You can use Reliza Hub that I work on to do 3. It will allow you to track releases of B and take action if a new release is produced, possibly based on approvals. You can find me on devopscommunity.org discord to discuss more.
